# Custom Plugin shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I need help about Custom Plugin in wordpress I want to change the color in sub menu settings in wordpress so I use this

```
 add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'PJ-Plugin Settings', 'PJ-Plugin Settings', 'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mysettings' );
}



 function pj_menu()
{
add_theme_page( 'Theme Option', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'pu_theme_options.php', 'pu_theme_page');  
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'pj_menu');

function register_mysettings() {
//register  settings
register_setting( 'pj_options', 'colors' );
}
function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
if(isset($_POST['colors'])){
    update_option('colors', $_POST['colors']);
}
echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>';
echo '<h2>PJ-Plugin Settings</h2>';

    ?>

<form method="post" nctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
      settings_fields('pj_options'); 

      do_settings_sections('pj_options');
      echo '<h3>Choose Color</h3>';
    ?>
<select name="colors">
  <option value="red"> red </option>
  <option value="blue"> blue </option>
  <option value="green"> green </option>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" name="one" />
</select>
</form>
 <?php
  echo '</div>';

}


function samp_func_1( $atts ){
global $options;
echo 'color : '.$color = get_option('colors');
$html = "<div class='forplug' style= 'color:".$color."'>Hello World</div>";
return $html;  
}
add_shortcode( 'hello_world', 'samp_func_1' );
```

Yes it is working but if I will update the page in where the shortcode is. My problem is that if I will choose the color and save the settings it will automatically change the color and not to update in the page. Maybe the problem is this code:

```
function samp_func_1( $atts ){
global $options;
echo 'color : '.$color = get_option('colors');
$html = "<div class='forplug' style= 'color:".$color."'>Hello World</div>";
return $html;
```

}

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. It works but your settingspage doesn't reflect the color chosen?

Comment: It is already functioning but when I select the page in the wordpress dashboard where my shortcode is then update that page. I want is that whenever I change the color in the setting and will just visit the page it will change the color automatically and not to update the page on the dashboard. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I am sorry I still don't understand. Maybe someone else will.